# Pandas: Assign back to table from grouping by column and index

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, indexing

I am trying to implement Exponential Moving Average calculation on a `DataFrame`. The formula is

[image: EMA]

An additional complication is that my table is grouped and there is a unique bin number per group. This is what I tried

```
import numpy as np
import numpy.random as rand

n = 5
groups = np.array(['one', 'two', 'three'])
data = pd.DataFrame({
    'price': rand.random(3 * n) * 10,
    'group': np.repeat(groups, n),
    'bin': np.tile(np.arange(n),3)}, index=np.arange(3 * n))

print(data)
```

`price  group  bin
0   1.601310    one    0
1   3.190662    one    1
2   4.419421    one    2
3   3.817510    one    3
4   2.440774    one    4
5   6.832265    two    0
6   5.636502    two    1
7   4.630515    two    2
8   5.856423    two    3
9   0.916452    two    4
10  4.247134  three    0
11  7.146746  three    1
12  8.049161  three    2
13  7.852168  three    3
14  0.246720  three    4`

This is how I am trying to implement the EMA calculation;

```
data['EMA'] = np.zeros(len(data.index))
data.loc[data['bin'] == 0, 'EMA'] = data.loc[data['bin'] == 0, 'price']

a = 2 / (n + 1)
for _, group in data.groupby('group'):
    for index, row in group.iloc[1:].iterrows():
        prev = group[group['bin'] == row['bin'] - 1].iloc[0]
        row['EMA'] = a * row['price'] + (1 - a) * prev['EMA'] # nope
        data.loc[index, 'EMA'] = a * row['price'] + (1 - a) * prev['EMA'] # nope
```

Unfortunately neither of these last lines update the values in the group. On the second iteration, the value of `prev['EMA']` is still 0. What is the correct way to assign the values back to the table such that it is updated dynamically? Do I need to write out to a temporary array and write it back afterwards?

Additionally, I could not think of an elegant way to do this using `assign` or `transform`. If someone can solve that it might be a very good alternative.

---

## Response

Thank you @DaFanat for your help. Unfortunately your code doesn't work. I tried the following

```
data.loc[:, 'EMA2'] = map(lambda x, y: x if pd.isnull(y) else x*a + (1-a) * y, 
data['price'], data.groupby('group')['price'].shift(1))
```

But I get an error `TypeError: object of type 'map' has no len()`. I tried changing it to this

```
data['EMA2'] = list(map(lambda x, y: x if pd.isnull(y) else x*a + (1-a) * y, 
data['price'], data.groupby('group')['price'].shift(1)))
```

And I do indeed get some results, but they do not look correct;

`price  group  bin       EMA      EMA2
0   5.407722    one    0  5.407722  5.407722
1   0.495734    one    1  3.770393  3.770393
2   7.911491    one    2  5.150759  2.967653
3   1.085836    one    3  3.795785  5.636272
4   7.326432    one    4  4.972667  3.166035`

I am inclined to believe my implementation, since the price goes up from 0.5 to 7.9, how can the moving average go down? I think the indices are getting lost and it is putting the values against the wrong cells. How do I retain the indices when performing this calculation?

---

## Solution

Thanks @DaFanat, you took me a long way. I finally figured out how to do it with a slight modification of your original method;

```
data['EMA2'] = data.groupby('group') \
                   .apply(lambda x: x['price'] * a + x['EMA'].shift(1) * (1-a)) \
                   .reset_index(level=0, drop=True)
data.loc[data['bin'] == 0, 'EMA2'] = data.loc[data['bin'] == 0, 'price']

print(data)
```

`price  group  bin       EMA      EMA2
0   3.556171    one    0  3.556171  3.556171
1   5.637241    one    1  4.249861  4.249861
2   3.278771    one    2  3.926164  3.926164
3   7.343718    one    3  5.065349  5.065349
4   6.128884    one    4  5.419861  5.419861`

Not using the `list(map())` ensures that the result is a `DataFrame` with indices retained, so it knows where to insert the individual rows.

Comment: Is it not the same as using the Dataframe.ewm().mean() ?

Answer (score 2):

#### EDIT:

Couldnt find a clean solution but this function should do the trick

```
def calc_ema(cur, *prevs):
    rele_prevs = [x for x in prevs if not pd.isnull(x)]
    rele_prevs_cnt = len(rele_prevs)
    if rele_prevs_cnt == 0:##First item
       res = cur
    else:
       x0 = rele_prevs[rele_prevs_cnt-1]
       prev_items_sum = sum([x * ((1-a) ** (i+1)) for i, x in 
       enumerate(rele_prevs)])
       st = a * (cur + prev_items_sum)
       res =  st + ((1-a) ** (rele_prevs_cnt+1)) * x0
    return res
```

You should use it as follows:

```
grpd = data.groupby('group')
data['EMA3'] = list(map(calc_ema, data['price'], *[grpd['price'].shift(i) for i in range(1, n + 1)]))
```

#### Original Answer:

-- Dosnt answer OP's needs --

You can use the [shift](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.shift.html) function on a grouped by object.
This will let you calculate on $Y_t$ and $Y_{t-1}$

```
data.sort_values(by='bin', inplace=True)
a = 0.1
data.loc[:, 'ema'] = map(lambda x, y: x if pd.isnull(y) else x*a + (1-a) * y, 
data['price'], data.groupby('group')['price'].shift(1))

##python 3  
 data.loc[:, 'ema'] = list(map(lambda x, y: x if pd.isnull(y) else x*a + (1-a) * y, 
data['price'], data.groupby('group')['price'].shift(1)))
```

Comment: Hmm. Did you execute this code? I get an error `TypeError: object of type 'map' has no len()`

Comment: Python 3 related -- use llst(map(....)) and it will work

Comment: I get the same incorrect results as in my Response section in the question. I think the indices are not being respected.

Comment: OK, checked and your new implementation works, but it is even more code than I have originally. I was hoping there would be something more elegant. Thanks for the efforts though.

Answer (score 1):

I figured it out by using a temporary array as mentioned, but the result is ugly as hell

```
a = 2 / (n + 1)
for _, group in data.groupby('group'):
    ema = np.zeros(len(group.index))
    ema[0] = group.iloc[0]['price']
    i = 1
    for index, row in group.iloc[1:].iterrows():
        ema[i] = a * row['price'] + (1 - a) * ema[i-1]
        data.loc[index, 'EMA'] = ema[i]
        i = i + 1

print(data)
```

`price  group  bin       EMA
0   5.121409    one    0  5.121409
1   6.359162    one    1  5.533993
2   0.841837    one    2  3.969941
3   9.348758    one    3  5.762880
4   3.671258    one    4  5.065673
5   1.651604    two    0  1.651604
6   7.940099    two    1  3.747769
7   8.777750    two    2  5.424429
8   8.227762    two    3  6.358873
9   3.283300    two    4  5.333682
10  8.290492  three    0  8.290492
11  8.589680  three    1  8.390221
12  0.159063  three    2  5.646502
13  5.504104  three    3  5.599036
14  9.392295  three    4  6.863456`

I'm not going to accept my answer because there has to be a more elegant way of doing it. Any offers?